# 'window.location.replace' redirects to the given page but destroies the session from php (Chrome only)?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I know that the question is a bit confusing but here is the case.

I have the following Ajax function:

```
    $.ajax({
    url:"../controllers/xx_register.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:send,
    success: function(response){
        if (response=="1") {
            window.location.replace("http://localhost/Underground/01.InProgress/ES-dictionary/public/index.php");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            $('#error').append(response);
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        $('#error').append('Fatal error!');
    }       
});
return false;
```

the xx_register.php file:

```
$arr=$_POST;

$reg = registerMe($arr);

if ($reg === true) {
    $_SESSION['is_logged']=$arr['username'];
    echo 1;
    exit();
}   
else{
    echo($reg);
    exit();
}
```

finally the index.php

```
    session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['is_logged'])) {
    header("Location: ../views/start.php");
    exit();
    }
else{
    header("Location: ../views/login.php");
    exit();
}
```

**Shortly - the idea:**
I use ajax function for registering a new users. If everything is ok with the registration the user will be redirected to `index.php`. As the `$_SESSION['is_logged']` exist the user will be redirected to the `start.php` page.

This all works for FireFox 21, IE 10, Safari 5.1 but on Chrome 27 the thing are quite different - the user is again redirected to `loggin.php`. The simple logic is pointing that `window.location.replace` is redirecting to `index.php` and clearing the session. I really don't see any explanation. 
Two questions:
1. Am I correct about the issue with the  `window.location.replace`?
2. How to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.replace()` for this, just assign the value directly.

This is fix:

```
window.location = "http://localhost/Underground/01.InProgress/ES-dictionary/public/index.php";
```

Comment: thanks for the advise. It didn't worked again but then i found why. I have turned off the cookies. Can't believe that spend so much time and even wasted yours and all others time because of such simple thing.